# I want to simply subtract elements from two lists

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have two open lists. First Weight (`fWeight`) and Second Weight (`sWeight`). I want to subtract the `fWeight` from `sWeight`. I am getting this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'.
```

Is there a a simple solution for this?

```python
names_array = list()
firstWeight_Array=list()
students = 2
for i in range(students):
    name = str(raw_input("Please enter a  name:"))
    names_array.append(str(name))
    fWeight = int(raw_input("Please enter the first weight:"))
    firstWeight_Array.append(int(fWeight))

SecondWeight_Array=list()
for i in range(students):
        sWeight = int(raw_input("Please enter the Second weight:"))
        SecondWeight_Array.append(int(sWeight))

print(firstWeight_Array,SecondWeight_Array)
print firstWeight_Array - SecondWeight_Array
```

Answer (score 1):

The substraction operator is not defined for `list`, as it makes no sense in a general way. However, you can simply get the single items using the `[]` operator, and calculate the difference in a new `list`:

```
newArray = list();
for i in xrange(students):
    newArray.append(firstWeight_Array[i] - secondWeight_Array[i]);
print newArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the error: ValueError: 0 is not in list

Comment: I would use `xrange` instead of `range` in case that it is python2

Answer (score 1):

If you need to subtract every item from one list to the corresponding item of a second list of same size, the easiest way (and probably the most idiomatic way) is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) function:

```
diff = [first - second 
        for first, second in zip(firstWeight_Array, secondWeight_Array)]
```

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> firstWeight_Array = [10,20,30]
>>> secondWeight_Array = [12,18,34]

>>> diff = [first - second 
...         for first, second in zip(firstWeight_Array, secondWeight_Array)]

>>> diff
[-2, 2, -4]
```

Please note that for space efficiency reason, in Python 2, you might prefer using [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of a plain `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
diffs = [firstWeight_Array[i] - secondWeight_Array[i] for i in xrange(len(students))]
```

In case that you work with Python 3, use `range` instead of `xrange`