# Trying to calculate profit to return to my website

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to calculate if you will make a profit out of two items from a game, now I need to do
"NPC buy price - the sell price * 640", reason being is that you can only buy 640 of the item, and well first off I need the margin, that's why NPC buy price - sell price.

This is how my python looks:

```
@app.route('/bresell')
def reSell():
    farmingMerchantPrices = [
        "5",  # cocoa beans
        "12",  # brown mushroom
        "2.33",  # carrot
        "8",  # pumpkin
        "2.33",  # wheat
        "12",  # red mushroom
        "2.33",  # potato
        "4",  # sand
        "5",  # sugar cane
        "2",  # melon
    ]
    farmingMerchantName = [
        "Cocoa Beans",
        "Brown Mushroom",
        "Carrot",
        "Pumpkin",
        "Wheat",
        "Red Mushroom",
        "Potato",
        "Sand",
        "Sugar Cane",
        "Melon"
    ]
    sellPrice = []
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[not allowed to show key]').json()
    for x in farmingProducts:
        sellPrice.append(f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][0]["pricePerUnit"])
    profit = []
    for x in farmingMerchantPrices:
        profit.append(sellPrice - x)
    return render_template('resell.html', farmingMerchantPrices=farmingMerchantPrices, farmingMerchantName=farmingMerchantName, sellPrice=sellPrice, profit=profit)
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<tbody>
      {% for name, npcBuy,price,profit in zip(farmingMerchantName,
      farmingMerchantPrices,sellPrice,profit) %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>{{ profit will go here }}</td>
        <td>{{ npcBuy }}</td>
        <td>{{ price }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

I am a bit confused if I shall do the math in Jinja or flask, flask right? And I am a bit unsure how to actually do it!

Comment: It's preferable to do any calculations in the backend (flask here).. So, you're right

Comment: yeah because I think that my "npcBuy" is a string, and well my "profit" is a float value, so while trying to subtract them with each other I run into a few issues.. or can you subtract two arrays with each other? If I append sellprice (which I have), and then I have appended "farmingMerchantPrices", can I subtract first item in "farmingMerchantPrices" with first item in "sellPrice"?

Comment: I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515416/i-want-to-simply-subtract-elements-from-two-lists) thread, but I am getting error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, it's preferable to perform any calculations in the backend where your calculates are hidden and secure.

According to your second question, I think your only issue with your code is that you defined the prices in `farmingMerchantPrices` as strings not numbers. So, your issue should be resolved just by changing the type like so:

```
farmingMerchantPrices = [
        5,  # cocoa beans   (5 instead of "5")
        12,  # brown mushroom
        2.33,  # carrot
        8,  # pumpkin
        2.33,  # wheat
        12,  # red mushroom
        2.33,  # potato
        4,  # sand
        5,  # sugar cane
        2,  # melon
    ]
```

Comment: oh okay, well I tried that and did this: `for i in range(amount): profit = farmingMerchantPrices[i] - sellPrice[i]`, returned "profit" to my HTML, and getting error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: just kidding! Fixed it, had to do:

Comment: `profit = []
    zip_object = zip(farmingMerchantPrices, sellPrice)
    for farmingMerchantPrices_i, sellPrice_i in zip_object:
        profit.append(farmingMerchantPrices_i - sellPrice_i)`